# How do I keep running a Java Selenium script every five minutes when the system is shutdown and add the results onto a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: java, selenium, google-sheets-api

I've written a Program in Eclipse using Java and Selenium Webdriver to

1. Go to a website and check the value of a number on the website (say stock prices)
2. If the value of the number is different from the last time the script was run, the script runs, else it terminates. (if the current stock price is different from when the script was run last time, the script runs. If the value is the same as last time, then the script terminates)

How do I

1. Automatically run it every 5 minutes
2. Keep running it even when my system is turned off?
3. Transfer all data onto a Google Sheet as and when the script is run?

Comment: What do you mean by '_when my system is turned off_'? Completely shut down? That would be interesting.

Comment: For example, a remote system on the internet which is always on runs my code for me when my machine is turned off.

Comment: Or any other alternative to keep running my code when my system is off

Comment: Take a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Thank you! This helps with repeated periodic execution.

Comment: You have to create jar and then put into the server and setup the cronjob that run on the server on a specific time given in cronjob.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I am seeking a similar solution to my challenge. I am running through a test suite which initially Polls and detects a file in a directory using a watch service API built into Java, but once my execution is complete I would like the script to start Polling that directory again and be ready for the next incoming file, any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question as want to loop and repeat the **`Test Execution`** at pre-defined interval and other conditions, there can be a couple of options available as follows :

### Automatic Loops :

- You can use the [**`ScheduledExecutorService`** **Interface**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) from **`java.util.concurrent`**
- Use a **`Continous Integration`** tool like [**`Jenkins`**](https://jenkins.io/) to support building, deploying and automating any project.
- You can use the functionalities extended by **`Windows Scheduler`** to start your **`Test Execution`**.
- Configure a **`Cron Job`** to execute your **`Test Suite`** at pre-defined intervals.

### Execution when system is turned off :

- Use [**`BrowserStack`**](https://www.browserstack.com/)
- Use [**`SauceLabs`**](https://saucelabs.com/)

### Transfer all data into Cloud

- Use [**`G Suite`**](https://gsuite.google.com/signup/basic/welcome)

Comment: I am seeking a similar solution to my challenge. I am running through a test suite which initially Polls and detects a file in a directory using a watch service API built into Java, but once my execution is complete I would like the script to start Polling that directory again and be ready for the next incoming file, any solution to this?